# (iWork) Numbers: Cut and Paste, macros

Tags: macos, big-sur, numbers, iwork

Is there a way to "cut" certain cells and paste them to another cells or sheet without losing formulas with references to other cells (such as MS Excel does with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Numbers does not support Excel macros at all?

Answer (score 1):

One way to cut formula and paste in new location with references 'in tact and relative' is following:

- navigate to desired cell containing formula
- <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⏎</kbd> ('enter cell edit mode', same as F2 in Windows Excel)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ('select all')
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> ('cut')
- <kbd>⏎</kbd> ('exit cell')
- navigate to destination cell
- <kbd>=</kbd> (opens popup window for entering formula)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ('paste')

Alternatively one can make references in formula absolute with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then cut-paste whole cell.

Comment: This is basically the only thing I came up with, however, such method is unfortunately very ineffective if I need to copy a whole table with equations, text etc.

Comment: If you 'came up' with this before asking the question it would have been nice if you worded your question differently. If you need to copy a whole table then you can duplicate it with ⌘ + D and move it where needed. If there are references to cells outside of the table then they should be made absolute before duplicating table.

Comment: Well, I though that copying just the formula to any other cell was obvious as a solution, you can do that in any table's editor. I will look at the post formulation, but to me, the problem is specified correctly. Duplicating a table is also another thing. To put my issue in a simplified way, what I try to achieve is a direct equivalent (if any exists) to cut & paste in MS Excel no matter the size of an area I am moving elsewhere. Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Comment: My English may let me down but if question is '`Is there a way` to "cut" certain cells and paste them to another cells or sheet without losing formulas with references to other cells'   then for me it means that questioner don't even know whether such way exists. Numbers has also drag-and-drop (press and hold, drag) which in functionality is pretty similar to Excel's cut-and-paste.